# creating a new server in SQL Management studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssms

The question is about as simple as it gets but for the life of me i cant find out anywhere online about how to create a new server. NOT a new database inside of a server, i already know how to do that, but an entirely new server on my PC. Im using SQL management studio 2012.

Comment: You mean a new database *instance*?  You might have to re-run the installer for that, as it involves setting up a lot more than just some data.

Comment: Do you mean you need to add an _existing_ SQL Server to the server list in Management Studio?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install a new instance using the install media.

There is no way to do that from SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: oh so its when SQL management studio is installed when you create a server? do i have to run the install again to create another server alongside the one already on my machine?

Comment: @π-e - No. SQL Server instances and SQL Server Management Studio are different things. You don't have to install them together. But there is a SQL Server installer that you need to run again to install _another_ server instance.